# Punctuation and omission: what is possible to write?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I understand that the only difference here is about tense and punctuation, for example, in B, "[;] you country has not". The word "rule" will always be omitted or is D also possible?

A. My country has rules, while yours has not.

B. My country has rules; your country has not.

C. My country has rules, while your country has not.

D. My country has rules, while your country has not rules.

D sounds utterly wrong because it does not use zeugma.

I am sorry if this question has been asked before. If so, I am trying to find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's optional, not incorrect, to resay "rules".
Also, I would suggest using "does".
I put the optional parts in brackets:

1. My country has rules, while yours does not [have rules].
2. My country has rules; your country does not [have rules].
3. My country has rules, while your country does not [have rules].

edit: more acceptable sentences:

4. My country has rules, while yours has none.
5. My country has rules; your country has none.
6. My country has rules, while your country has no rules.